# Problem with Converting a bootstrap site to React

Tags: reactjs

I want to convert a bootstrap  to a react file i did all the changes but i get this error

```
./src/css/jquery-ui.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/css/jquery-ui.min.css)
```

Module not found: Can't resolve './images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png' in 'E:\React\tejapak\src\css'

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It' looks like you imported jquery's css in some component and deleted jQuery dependencies without removing import.

Search if there any place where jquery-ui.min.css is included in component and remove it.